# Flagging values based on subsequent occurences using first. retain etc

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Thank you who will be able to help me. I've got a dataset as below:

```
data smp;
infile datalines dlm=',';
informat identifier $7. trx_date $9. transaction_id $13. product_description $50. ;
input identifier $ trx_date transaction_id $ product_description $ ;
datalines;
Cust1,11Aug2016,20-0030417313,ONKEN BIOPOT F/FREE STRAWBERRY
Cust1,11Aug2016,20-0030417313,ONKEN BIOPOT F/FREE STRAWBERRY
Cust1,11Aug2016,20-0030417313,ONKEN BIOPOT FULL STRAWB/GRAIN
Cust1,11Aug2016,20-0030417313,RACHELS YOG GREEK NAT F/F/ORG
Cust1,03Nov2016,23-0040737060,RACHELS YOG GREEK NAT F/F/ORG
Cust3,13Feb2016,39-0070595440,COLLECT YOG LEMON
Cust3,21Jun2016,34-0050769524,AF YOG FARMHOUSE STRAWB/REDCUR
Cust3,21Jun2016,34-0050769524,Y/VALLEY GREEK HONEY ORGANIC
Cust3,21Jun2016,34-0050769524,Y/VALLEY THICK LEMON CURD ORG
Cust3,21Jun2016,34-0050769524,Y/VALLEY THICK YOG FRUITY FAVS
Cust3,21Jun2016,34-0050769524,Y/VALLEY THICK YOG STRAWB ORG
Cust3,26Jun2016,39-0430106897,TOTAL GREEK YOGURT 0%
Cust3,14Aug2016,54-0040266755,M/BUNCH SQUASHUMS STRAW/RASP
Cust3,14Aug2016,54-0040266755,MULLER CORNER STRAWBERRY
Cust3,14Aug2016,54-0040266755,TOTAL GREEK YOGURT 0%
Cust3,22Aug2016,54-0050447336,M/BUNCH SQUASHUMS STRAW/RASP
;
```

For each customers (and each of their purchase based on transaction_id), i'm wanting to flag each product that will be repurchased during their next visit (only their next visit) on a rolling basis. So in the above dataset, correct flags would be on rows 4,12 and 13 because these products are bought on the next customer visit (we only look at the next visit).

I'm trying to do it with the following program:

```
proc sort data = smp out = td;
by descending identifier transaction_id product_description;
run;

DATA TD2(DROP=tmp_product);
SET td;
BY identifier transaction_id product_description;
RETAIN tmp_product;
IF FIRST.product_description and first.transaction_id THEN DO;
  tmp_product = product_description;
END;
ATTRIB repeat_flag FORMAT=$1.;
IF NOT FIRST.product_description THEN DO;
IF tmp_product EQ product_description THEN repeat_flag ='Y';
ELSE repeat_flag = 'N';
END;
RUN;

proc sort data = td2;
by descending identifier transaction_id product_description;
run;
```

But it's not working? if someone could pse help it would be fab.
Best Wishes

Comment: Your first two rows are the same product and same date. That will probably cause trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other method is to produce a dummy group in original dataset and temporary dataset. In original dataset, group is sequenced by visit time per customer, in temporary dataset, group is sequenced from beginning of SECOND visit time per customer, group number in temporary dataset is the same as group number of original dataset, but its visit time is next visit of original dataset. With the dummy group, it is easy to find the same product that was repurchased during their next visit by hash table.

```
proc sort data=smp;
by identifier trx_date;
run;

data have(drop=_group) temp(drop=group rename=(_group=group));
   set smp;
   by identifier trx_date; 
   if first.identifier then do;
     group=1; _group=0;
   end;
   if dif(trx_date)>0 then do;
      group+1; _group+1;
   end;
   if _group^=0 then output temp; 
   output have;
 run;

data want;
    if 0 then set temp;
    if _n_=1 then do;
       declare hash h(dataset:'temp');
       h.definekey('identifier','group','product_description');
       h.definedata('product_description');
       h.definedone();
    end;
    set have;
    flag=(h.find()=0);
    drop group;
run;
```

Comment: Don't really need a dummy group here, you can just look up the next group interactively in the hash find (`h.find(key:group+1)` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

The method below will "look ahead" to the next row (opposite to LAG) after sorting so you can bring comparisons onto the same row for simple logic:

```
** convert character date to numeric **;
data smp1; set smp;
    TRX_DATE_NUM = input(TRX_DATE,ANYDTDTE10.);
    format TRX_DATE_NUM mmddyy10.;
run;

** sort **;
proc sort data = smp1;
    by IDENTIFIER PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION TRX_DATE_NUM;
run;

** look ahead at the next observations and use logic to identify flags **;
data look_ahead;
    set smp1;
    by IDENTIFIER;
    set smp1 (firstobs = 2 
                keep = IDENTIFIER PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION TRX_DATE_NUM 
                rename = (IDENTIFIER = NEXT_ID PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = NEXT_PROD TRX_DATE_NUM = NEXT_DT))
        smp1 (obs = 1 drop = _ALL_);
    if last.IDENTIFIER then do;
        NEXT_ID = "";
        NEXT_PROD = "";
        NEXT_DT = .;
    end;
run;

** logic says if the next row is the same customer who bought the same product on a different date then flag **;
data look_ahead_final; set look_ahead;
    if IDENTIFIER = NEXT_ID and NEXT_PROD = PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION and TRX_DATE_NUM ne NEXT_DT then FLAG = 1;
        else FLAG = 0;
run;
```

Comment: I think this has the same problem Tom's answer does; this checks they buy it ever again, but not that they bought it in the immediately next visit.

Comment: Hi, it does indeed check whether they buy ever again, which is very near but not the same as whether they by immediately at the next visit. If one adds the following line of data (Cust3,26dec2016,66-0070595440,COLLECT YOG LEMON) , COLLECT YOG LEMON gets wrongly flagged on 13feb2016.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this; I think the simplest to understand, while still having a reasonable level of performance, is to sort the data in descending date order and then use an array to store the product_descriptions of the last trx_date.

Here I use a 2 dimensional array where the first dimension is just a 1/2 value; each trx_date simultaneously loads one row of the array and checks against the other row of the array (using `_array_switch` to determine which is being loaded/checked).

You could do the same thing with a hash table, and it would be appreciably faster along with perhaps a bit less complicated in some ways; if you are familiar with hash tables and want to see that solution comment and I or someone else can provide it.

You also could use SQL to do this, and I suspect that is the most common solution overall, but I couldn't quite get it to work, as it has some complexity with subqueries within subqueries the way I was approaching it, and I'm apparently not good enough with those.

Here's the array solution.  Set the second dimension of `prods` to a reasonable maximum for your data - it could even be thousands, this is a temporary array and does not use much memory so set to 32000 or whatever would not be a big deal.

```
proc sort data=smp;
  by identifier descending trx_date ;
run;

data want;
  array prods[2,20] $255. _temporary_;
  retain _array_switch 2;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.trx_date);
    set smp;
    by identifier descending trx_date;
    /* for first row for an identifier, clear out the whole thing */
    if first.identifier then do;
      call missing(of prods[*]);
    end;

    /* for first row of a trx_date, clear out the array-row we were looking at last time, and switch _array_switch to the other value */
    if first.trx_date then do;
      do _i = 1 to dim(prods,2);
        if missing(prods[_array_switch,_i]) then leave;
        call missing(prods[_array_switch,_i]);
      end;
      _array_switch = 3-_array_switch;
    end;

    *now check the array to see if we should set next_trans_flag;

    next_trans_flag='N';
    do _i = 1 to dim(prods,2);
      if missing(prods[_array_switch,_i]) then leave;  *for speed;
      if prods[_array_switch,_i] = product_description then next_trans_flag='Y';      
    end;
    prods[3-_array_switch,_n_] = product_description;  *set for next trx_date;
    output;
  end;
  drop _:;
run;
```

Comment: .Hi, i checked and this seems to work! thank you so much -)

Answer (score 0):

I think to really answer this you need to generate a list of distinct visit*product combinations. And also a list of the distinct products bought on particular visits.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  create table bought as 
    select distinct identifier, product_description, trx_date, transaction_id
    from smp
    order by 1,2,3,4
  ;
  create table all_visits as 
    select a.identifier, product_description, trx_date, transaction_id
    from (select distinct identifier,product_description from bought) a
    natural join (select distinct identifier,transaction_id,trx_date from bought) b
    order by 1,2,3,4
  ;
quit;
```

You can then combine them and make a flag for whether the product was bought on that visit.

```
data check ;
  merge all_visits bought(in=in1) ;
  by identifier product_description trx_date transaction_id ;
  bought=in1;
run;
```

You can now use a `lead` technique to figure out if the they also bought the product on the next visit.

```
data flag ;
  set check ;
  by identifier product_description trx_date transaction_id ;
  set check(firstobs=2 keep=bought rename=(bought=bought_next)) check(drop=_all_ obs=1);
  if last.product_description then bought_next=0;
run;
```

You can then combine back with the actual purchases and eliminate the extra dummy records.

```
proc sort data=smp;
  by identifier product_description trx_date transaction_id ;
run;

data want ;
  merge flag smp (in=in1);
  by identifier product_description trx_date transaction_id ;
  if in1 ;
run;
```

Let's put the records back into the original order so we can check the results.

```
proc sort; by row; run;
proc print; run;
```

[image]